# SQL query, error

Tags: plugins, query, sql

I have sql query:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from, $site WHERE custom > 0";
```

but not work, i have notice:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: Order by has to be after where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `where` clause of the query in the wrong place.

Your query should be written like this:

`$query= "SELECT * 
          FROM files 
          WHERE custom > 0 
          ORDER BY id DESC 
          LIMIT $from, $site";`

As specified here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html in the MySQL reference.